# Europe during these years seemed to prove that such was possible

Tags: syntactic-analysis, such

My question is as to the usage of the word such in the following [passage](http://www.sparknotes.com/history/european/1871-1914/context.html) .

> The order of the day was, quite simply, self- improvement, national
>   improvement, and attainable perfection; the great successes of Europe
>   during these years seemed to prove that such was possible.

I feel like the word such means " something like that" in the context but I could not find the structure of  this usage.As far as I know the word such is followed by a noun or adjective or both.

Could you please give me some references as to this usage of the word such.

Answer (score 2):

*Such* can be used as a noun, but it is unusual outside legal texts. It means "such a thing, that".

Answer (score 1):

"Such" is functioning as a pronoun, meaning "something like those" where the antecedents are two types of improvement and one type of perfection.